# angular $watch|| if statement not executed when one element left?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am doing watch on result of filtering if it change watch is making loop and creating new objects, everything works fine until one item left as result.

```
$scope.$watch('ResultOfFiltering', function(newValue, oldValue) {

  console.log('watch started');

  if (newValue !== oldValue) {
    $scope.dataMap.features = $scope.ResultOfFiltering;

    console.log('First Condition');

    $scope.LimitDescription = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.dataMap.features, function(value, key) {
      if (key) {
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.dataMap.features.length; i++) {
          $scope.LimitDescription[i] = 40;

          console.log($scope.LimitDescription[i]);

        }
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.log('First Condition False');
  }
}, true);
```

I mounted two console logs and when I have one item in `ResultOfFiltering` then in console I see that two logs were fired, so it should mean that first if statement was fired as true, but it stops on last log `"First Condition"` and the rest of if statement is not executed? `else` statement is never executed so first `if` statement is always true, so what's going on here?

Possible cause?

Okey I haven't notice first but it seems that the problem is with nested if(key) statement, when one element left key has value 0 and zero has boolean value false? I am right?

Comment: If `console.log('First Condition')` is fired, then definitely the next few lines of code are executed. What is the result that you expect?

Comment: I putted console.log as well after for lop and nothing is displayed in console?

Comment: That just means that the condition to enter the for loop is not met. Use a debugger. This has nothing really to do with Angular or `$watch`

Comment: Okey i think i know the issue the problem is with nested if (key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
if(key){
```

You're looping through an array, so your first index is 0, and 0 is falsey.

I also question why you have a for loop inside a foreach loop, when both are looping through the same array. Kinda pointless...